# Android version on Google TV devices

Tags: google-tv

As per my understanding Google TV devices available in markets donot yet run on HoneyComb. If thats right, could you please let me know the Android version they run on?
Would the HoneyComb update to Google TV be released as a new API level or a revision version for Honeycomb?When can we expect the same?

Answer (score 1):

Here's details:

> These are the system requirements for Google TV application
>   development:
>
> ```
> SDK Platform Android 3.1, API 12 (or later).
> Android SDK Tools revision 12 (or later).
> Android SDK Platform-tools revision 6 (or later).
> ```

(via http://code.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_setup_android.html)

You can [hack your Revue](http://androidandme.com/2011/08/news/video-heres-how-to-install-the-honeycomb-update-on-your-logitech-revue/) or wait for an official update.

Answer (score 0):

> If thats right, could you please let me know the Android version they run on?

Since you cannot write apps for them, it does not matter.

> Would the HoneyComb update to Google TV be released as a new API level or a revision version for Honeycomb?

We will find out when it ships. Most likely, it will be neither. TV-specific features (e.g., channel listings) will be accessed via an SDK add-on -- a preview of this is available to you now.

> When can we expect the same?

We will find out the ship date when it ships.